# How to detect two adjacent lines of a single-pixel-width line

Tags: image-processing

Imagine that there is a binary image, the 0 pixels are background and the 255 pixels are the single-pixel-width line. Now I am trying to detect two adjacent lines of the single-pixel-width line.

For example see below，there are two kinds of lines in the following pictures. The black one is the single-pixel-width line and the two red lines are what I am looking for. Is there any algorithm to detect the two adjacent lines?

[image: example 1] [image: example 2]

Comment: Do you really mean you want to detect them? Are they actually in your image? Or do you have the black ones and want to derive where the red ones would be? What else is in your picture? Are the lines actually black and red? Sorry, I find your question confusing.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thanks and I re-edit my description. Please review it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking whether it is a) invariant to a morphological opening with a 3x3 structuring element, and b) falls to pieces under morphological opening with a 5x5 structuring element.

You then want to erode with the 3x3 element, and subtract from the original image.